Why do websites have an entire page dedicated for login?
Wouldn't it be more user friendly to have the user stay at the page they're on and be given a dropdown box to login when they click a login button?

Some people or browsers intentionally disable Javascript, which means that some interactions won't work, unless you use a separate page.

Yes, it would be easier to have a dropdown/dialog/modal right as one clicks on the login button. From a UX perspective, you want the flow to an action as important as logging-in/signing-up to have as few steps as is possible. Unfortunately, modals come with their own fun issues:

Modals are annoying to manage from a development perspective, if you've made one from scratch or had to manage the URL based on whether a modal is open or not, you'll know what I'm saying.
SEO, Google can't show your login page as a suggestion on the SERPs page (SEO traffic is very important for a lot of companies).

Also, you don't want your users to be distracted by all the info on the page. The login/signup step is usually an extremely important part of the user journey. Actually, most sites (with the exception of blogs/ecommerce/etc.), spend most of the time on the home page trying to convince you to sign up or make the login process a breeze (e.g. github.com, asana.com, etc.). So, making that as streamlined with as little distractions as is possible is a priority.

Also, for complex signup/login forms, the space available in a modal might not be enough.


Being an old-timer, I recall many pages have had a simple Login/Password snippet somewhere besides the other, main content. It worked well - if you look at GMX.NET, it still does.
With the advent of two-factor authentication and social media login, space might actually be the main driver for a separate page/modal.
I don't believe the Javascript argument, as virtually no page works without Javascript these days anyway.

I still model my stuff after this. But it is definitely more suitable for a desktop experience (especially with the standard "top, left sidebar, content, right sidebar, bottom" layout)
